# How to withdraw all funds from a Ripple account?

Tags: ripple

I'm trying to close my account by withdrawing all my XRP into a new account. But the Ripple client insists on keeping a minimum balance of 50 XRP. How can I properly close this account?

Comment: Unfortunately, we have not yet figured out a way to do this. Removing an account completely would break our wallet security model.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Can someone who has access to the secret key steal this minimum balance of 50 XRP?

Comment: Not today, but if in the future either the reserve drops or the network does adopt a way to close an account, then they could.

Answer (score 2):

You can't withdraw the deposit, just leave it as it is.

Remove all trust and all offers to lower the minimum deposit.

Comment: 50 is currently the minimum.

Comment: 20 is now the maximum.

Answer (score -2):

totally a scam. Using the word “reserve” for mandatory contribution . The consumer has all the rights for there money. ITS A SCAM!!

Comment: well. your answer voices a very personal opinion. please be more objective in your next answer.

Comment: Down voted because this is not an answer to the OP explaining how to remove all funds from an account. This is just a venting rant.